# Pynput can't print accented character

Tags: python

edit: solved by adding encoding:'utf-8' as parameter when opening the file

I'm using Pynput to code an educative keylogger. The program records each keyboard touch released and writes it in a log.txt file.

```
# coding: utf-8

import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


TESTING = True


def on_release(key):

    if TESTING and key == Key.esc:
        return False

    logfile = open("log.txt", "a")
    logfile.write("[{0}]    [{1}]\n".format(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), str(key).strip("'")))


with Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The problem is that when I enter characters like: 'é' or 'è' I get a � in my log file. How do I fix this ?

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46271690/keyboard-input-as-unicode-characters-in-python